# How should one know if he is under Black Magic\evil spirits?

Tags: tantra, evil, ghosts

How could one know he is under Black Magic/ Evil spirits? How can one be sure? What symptoms can one feel, if he/she is under Black Magic?

Do scriptures/Tantric texts provide indications of such a person?

Comment: It doesn't seems related to hinduism at all.

Comment: I just wanted to know what the scriptures say on this? Hinduism talks about everything @TheHungryDictator

Comment: This is a valid Q .. when someone is under the spell of black magic there are definitely some symptoms .. some Tantric scriptures might describe those symptoms ... so please wait for an answer. @Shashaank

Comment: Thank you @Rickross

Comment: this is a valid question.just needs some editing.

Comment: Can you edit it @Visheshreddy accordingly?